# Audio Driver for HP a1510n with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers

I recently obtained an HP Pavilion a1510n desktop with no RAM or hard drive. I put in four sticks of 512MB DDR400 RAM, an HD4350 256MB and a Hitachi 160GB SATA II HDD with Windows 7 Home Premium 32-bit. (Standard specs include AMD Athlon 64 3800+ @ 2.4 GHz.) All drivers appear to be present. However, the audio icon on the taskbar has a red X over it and I'm not getting any sound out of my machine. HP's support site doesn't have any Windows 7 drivers/support (as usual) and I'm trying to look for the driver itself. The motherboard's on board audio is listed as "Built in Azalia 8 channel audio" and "Realtek ALC883 8-channel High Definition Audio CODEC". Does anyone have a possible solution to my problem?

**Solution:** Well, there isn't one really. However, I managed to get the onboard audio working for a short period of time. I downloaded the UAA HD hotfix from MS (KB835221) and installed the FRE version of the hotfix. Afterwards, I installed the original Realtek audio drivers from the HP site. The audio was working well, but after a restart, the audio was kaput again. I was fed up, so I got a Creative SB Live! sound card used for $10 and I'm having no problems with XP. *NOTE: I tried installing Windows 7, but getting the sound card to work is too much of a hassle. Windows 7 doesn't recognize it from the start and some special drivers must be downloaded for it to work.*

Comment: What shows up under audio devices in Device Manager?

Comment: Surprisingly there's no visible problems under the Device Manager. There appears to be a "functioning" high definition audio driver, in fact. If I uninstalled this in the DM, would this fix it?

Comment: In response to my own comment... no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [unknown device identifier](http://www.zhangduo.com/udi.html) will give you specifics about the device. You can find out exactly what chipset it uses and go to the manufacturer's page to find the correct drivers. I end up having to do this fairly frequently for various hardware.

Comment: I tried it but nothing came up. It just seems that the Realtek ALC883 audio chipset never had Windows 7 support. Another thought though... if I were to run Windows XP Mode within Windows 7 Professional, could I install the audio driver for XP that way?

Comment: This answer provided me with some new tools, even though it didn't solve the problem. My own solution is posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the [Vista Driver](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=pv-46403-2&lc=en&dlc=&cc=us&os=2093&product=3184138&sw_lang=&key=null&site=null) needs to be installed, and that will do the job.

Comment: But it doesn't work... as the driver is supported for versions up to and including Vista.

Comment: @Wesley, Vista and Windows 7 have very similar driver models. You can probably extract the driver files from the setup and use Device Manager to point Windows at the folder you extracted the driver to.

Comment: Did that already and there is still no audio. Even downloading Realtek drivers from other sites did not do anything. Would resorting to a sound card solve the problem?